# What happens when updating a CRD schema in k8s without changing the CRD version?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The k8s documentation [Versions in CustomResourceDefinitions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/) talks about how to upgrade CRD schema and CRD objects from one version to another.

However, what will happen when I update/change a CRD schema WITHOUT updating its version?

Fr example, I have a CRD schema `v1/Foo` and two field `A,B` (written in go):

```golang
// api version: v1
type FOOSpec struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
    B int `json:"b"`
}
```

I use kubebuilder to generate the CRD manifest and apply it in the k8s cluster. After that, The field A is deleted.

```golang
// still api version: v1
type FOOSpec struct {
    B int `json:"b"`
}
```

Again I generate the CRD manifest and apply it in the k8s cluster. Surprisingly k8s simply accept the updated CRD schema and no warning is reported.

Why is that? What if I create a Foo1 object of the first schema and then create a Foo2 object in the second schema. The two object has same version (v1) but the different schema.

I expect k8s to report an error when updating the CRD version without upgrading the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mostly answered your own question.

Custom Resource **Definitions** (CRDs) **define** Kubernetes resource types in the Kubernetes API.

In most schema evolutions, it is developers' responsibility to version such changes correctly. Kubernetes can't challenge the developer on the definition of schemas; it must accept the developers' intent (even if problematic).

The issue as you've observed, it that changing the definition of a Group*Version*Kind is problematic and therefore discouraged (in production).

If you create Resources against CRDs, then revise the CRD (without revising its Version) and create more Resources, you've introduced inconsistency:

- Removed fields are not accessible in **any** of the CRD's Resources
- Added|Changed fields aren't present in pre-change CRD's Resources

Errors will not arise until an operation (CRUD) is attempted (by the Kubernetes API server) against the Resource.

Kubernetes Kinds aren't SemVer versioned but follow a limited set of enumerations eg. v1alpha1, v1beta1, v1, v2 ... (see e.g. [Version priority](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/#version-priority)). During development I tend to use e.g. v1alpha1, make changes without bumping the version and manage the house-keeping. Once you publish a CRD, it's important to bump versions so that you do not break your users.